# Error building a container from a dart app

Tags: dart, docker

I am running Dart 1.85
I created a new project in the Dart editor with the name "server" using the ShelfServer template from the "new project" menu

I created a Dockerfile in the "server" directory with the following contents
FROM google/dart-runtime

The following is what I get when I try to build

dave@dave-DX4870:~/dart/server$ sudo docker build -t myapp3 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 17.92 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM google/dart-runtime

## Executing 4 build triggers

Step onbuild-0 : ADD pubspec.* /app/
2015/03/08 13:21:04 pubspec.*: no such file or directory
dave@dave-DX4870:~/dart/server$ ls
bin  CHANGELOG.md  Dockerfile  LICENSE  packages  pubspec.lock  pubspec.yaml  README.md
dave@dave-DX4870:~/dart/server$

Comment: Can you post the *actual* Dockerfile you're using? Are there actually files in the same directory as your Dockerfile that match the expression `pubspec.*`?

Answer (score 2):

To use the base image `google/dart-runtime` you need docker version 1.3.

In the base image google/dart-runtime we have the following line

`ONBUILD ADD pubspec.* /app/`

however the glob syntax for `ADD` is not supported before Docker version 1.3.